# Update stock using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli, shopping-cart

im currently working on an eCommerce website for college projects, and im trying to reduce the stock after the order is placed. can't figure where to put code lines that refer to "stock" row in the products table.
I will add the "action.php" code here.
im sorry for the long code, can't figure out what you will need to help.

```
<?php  
    session_start();
    require 'config.php';
    if(isset($_POST['pid'])){

        $pid = $_POST['pid'];
        $pname = $_POST['pname'];
        $pprice = $_POST['pprice'];
        $pimage = $_POST['pimage'];
        $pcode = $_POST['pcode'];
        $pqty = 1;

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT product_code FROM cart WHERE product_code=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$pcode);
        $stmt->execute();
        $res = $stmt->get_result();
        $r = $res->fetch_assoc();
        $code = $r['product_code'];

        if(!$code){
            $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cart (product_name,product_price,product_image,qty,total_price,product_code) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $query->bind_param("sssiss",$pname,$pprice,$pimage,$pqty,$pprice,$pcode);
            $query->execute();



            echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible mt-2">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                          <strong>Item added to your cart!</strong>
                        </div>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible mt-2">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                          <strong>Item already added to your cart!</strong>
                        </div>';
        }
    }

    if(isset($_GET['cartItem']) && isset($_GET['cartItem']) == 'cart_item'){
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $rows = $stmt->num_rows;

        echo $rows;
    }

    if(isset($_GET['remove'])){
        $id = $_GET['remove'];

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM cart WHERE id=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
        $stmt->execute();

        $_SESSION['showAlert'] = 'block';
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Item removed from the cart!';
        header('location:cart.php');
    }

    if(isset($_GET['clear'])){
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM cart");
        $stmt->execute();
        $_SESSION['showAlert'] = 'block';
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'All Item removed from the cart!';
        header('location:cart.php');
    }

    if(isset($_POST['qty'])){
        $qty = $_POST['qty'];
        $pid = $_POST['pid'];
        $pprice = $_POST['pprice'];

        $tprice = $qty*$pprice;

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE cart SET qty=?, total_price=? WHERE id=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("isi",$qty,$tprice,$pid);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

there is the "cart.php" code, tell me if you need anything else.

```
 <?php  
                require 'config.php';
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart");
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                $grand_total = 0;
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?= $row['id'] ?></td>
                <input type="hidden" class="pid" value="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
                <td><img src="<?= $row['product_image'] ?>" width="50"></td>
                <td><?= $row['product_name'] ?></td>
                <td>
                  <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= number_format($row['product_price'],2); ?>
                </td>
                <input type="hidden" class="pprice" value="<?= $row['product_price'] ?>">
                <td>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control itemQty" value="<?= $row['qty'] ?>" style="width:75px;">
                </td>
                <td><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= number_format($row['total_price'],2); ?></td>
                <td>
                  <a href="action.php?remove=<?= $row['id'] ?>" class="text-danger lead" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to remove this item?');"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <?php $grand_total +=$row['total_price']; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: PHPMyAdmin *is not* a database. It is a web interface for your MySQL database.

Comment: Yes,im sorry .. my bad.

Comment: I changed the title, can you please take a look at the code?

Comment: I only see code that deals with cart. What do you mean stock?

Comment: there is the all code you need:
action.php:
https://pastebin.com/4naXb14S
index.php:
https://pastebin.com/zVnqcWut
cart.php:
https://pastebin.com/SYHJVVgL

Answer (score 0):

the code that you posted only deals with carts table. you have also not shown the structure of your tables. I assume  you have another table that deals with product quantity. assuming the table name is product and you are able to get the quantity of each product ordered. here is how you can update the stock and how i updated it in my own project.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE product SET product_quantity = product_quantity-? WHERE product_id = ?   ");
        $stmt->bind_param("ii",$_POST['qty'],$_POST['pid']);
        $stmt->execute();
```

incase you add stock

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE product SET product_quantity = product_quantity+? WHERE product_id = ?   ");
        $stmt->bind_param("ii",$_POST['qty'],$_POST['pid']);
        $stmt->execute();
```

You can directly tell mysql to make calculation for you. you just have to tell the quantity,id and the operation